# Module '"<file path>/react-redux"' has no exported member 'Dispatch'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, redux, react-redux

I am following a [TypeScript-React-Starter tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter), and wrapping a component into a container, `Hello.tsx`. Line 4 is

```
import {connect, Dispatch} from 'react-redux';
```

and throws the following error on Dispatch:

```
Module '"../../node_modules/@types/react-redux"' has no exported member 'Dispatch'.
```

**How do I import Dispatch?**

Do I need to update something? `npm install` doesn't help, not even after updating to the latest npm version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Module '"../../node_modules/@types/react-redux"' has no exported member 'Dispatch'.
> ```

Looks like Dispatch is no longer part of react-redux; it's part of redux. Import Dispatch with

```
 import {Dispatch} from 'redux';
```

Keep connect with

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
```

Answer (score 1):

This really a breaking change. Dispatch is part of "redux" instead of "react-redux".

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
```

For more information visit [TypeScript-React-Starter Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter/issues/160)